# increment rotation while spacing and loading sprites around parentnode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

**Progress so far:** 
So what I have at the moment is this:
(the green point represents the parent "BlankNode, adding children then rotating them around that node, 
Im a bit stick how to get it work properly, for some reason they dont sit next to eachother but opposite (as showen in  https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7QvS.png)

**inGameLevel**

```
  myArc = [[Arcs alloc]initWithArcCount:myAmmountOfSprites];
  [self addChild:myArc];
```

My wish is for the sprite.rotation to be slightly offset from the next loaded...here they are split...
[image]

(The diagram belows showing the arc shape I would like to load the sprites  in) [image]

**With one stick loaded, maybe its easier to spot the mistake
(if I load a second sprite it loads directly opposite to the previous and not at the expected angle incremented

In this version I have just loaded the stick and blanknode, positioned it using anchor points, Im confused how the rotation works... **

```
    SKSpriteNode *blank = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]
    ///like the otherone
    blank.zRotation=0;
    blank.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    [self addChild:blank];

     //set to 0 value so I can see what its natural state is (it is vertical and above the parent node)
     //but this value will be incremented each time a new sprite is added
        int rotationAmount = 0;
        Rotation = Rotation-rotationAmount; //will increment

        objectPic = [SKSpriteNode spriteNode....as normal

        //use blank nodes anchorpoint
        objectPic.anchorPoint = blank.anchorPoint;

        //Rotation
        objectPic.zRotation = Rotation;

        float moveUp_donut = 0.3;
        //"moveUp_donut" moving this value up moves the stick up 
        //and outward from the center

        objectPic.anchorPoint = 
        CGPointMake(0.0,-moveUp_donut); //(0.0,-moveOutward);
        [blank addChild:objectPic];
}
```

}

[image][image: Loading second sprite ads it opposite and not next too the original]

**I have made an xcode project available for anyone interested to have a look at the problem, hopefully you can explain how to get the rotation working correctly.**

at the moment it is just loading one sprite, so you might need to play with the setting,

myArc = [[Arcs alloc]initWithArcCount:addLotsOfSticks];

//and play with the rotation ammount
 int rotationAmount = 3;

http://www.filedropper.com/rotationtest

**Solution Found! see below:**

**A huge thanks to WangYudong for giving such a great answer!**

Comment: Just thinking out load, What if you load all the bars (images) in single sprite, instead of using multiple sprites? A similiar approach https://github.com/hmaidasani/RadialChartImageGenerator

Comment: Ah, it seems that you have already positioned them correctly. Are you just seeking to move a sprite to next sprite location? May be animatewithduration can help. Inside code block for loop that moves sprite to next sprite location. The last sprite should be probably out of animation.

Comment: Yes (at the moment I seem to be able to rotate them somewhat ><, I think im just not understanding anchor point correctly, thanks ill update the code in a second and explain what the results are)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/he7joafmym3y6ml/StickRotation.zip?dl=0) and hope it can help. The algorithm is not base on your project, so make some change to fit your need.

Firstly, add a blank node to the middle of the scene:

```
self.blank = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor greenColor]size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
self.blank.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:self.blank];
```

Then, create the stick:

```
- (SKSpriteNode *)newStick
{
    SKSpriteNode *stick = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor redColor]size:CGSizeMake(5, 100)];
    return stick;
}
```

And given the amount of sticks, the radius (of the inner circle), the starting radian and ending radian, add a method:

```
- (void)loadStickArcWithStickAmount:(NSUInteger)amount radius:(CGFloat)radius startRadians:(CGFloat)startRad endRadians:(CGFloat)endRad
{
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < amount; index++) {
        SKSpriteNode *stick = [self newStick];

        CGFloat halfStickLength = stick.size.height / 2;
        CGFloat rotateRad = startRad + (endRad - startRad) / (amount - 1) * index;
        stick.zRotation = M_PI_2 + rotateRad;
        stick.position = CGPointMake((radius + halfStickLength) * cos(rotateRad),
                                     (radius + halfStickLength) * sin(rotateRad));
        [self.blank addChild:stick];
    }
}
```

Some hints:

- `rotateRad` divides radians of `endRad - startRad`.
- `M_PI_2` is an offset of `zRotation`.
- Trigonometric maths calculates the position of sticks.
- Both anchor points of blank node and stick remain default (0.5, 0.5).

Use the method:

```
[self loadStickArcWithStickAmount:27 radius:50.0 startRadians:M_PI endRadians:2*M_PI];
```

to achieve the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much xoxo its awesome, and works perfectly!! -  just what I was hoping to be able to do!